# Can a Butterfly Labs Jalapeño be used to mine Zetacoin?

Tags: mining-hardware, altcoin

Can my Butterfly Labs Jalapeño be switched to mine Zetacoin?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin ASICs like the old Butterfly Labs Jalapeno can do one thing and one thing only and that's SHA-256 hashing. Searches indicate Zetacoin uses SHA-256 hashing, so the answer is yes. Whether or not you will make any money is whole different story.